# Edges of line graph that is planar

Tags: graph-theory

When a graph $G$ is regular and planar, and its line graph is planar but not isomorphic to it, how many edges does L(G) have?

Answer (score 1):

If your graph has degree $d,$ the line graph has degree $2d - 2.$ For the graph to be planar, $2d -2 < 6,$ so $2d < 8,$ so $d = 1, 2, 3.$ I Note, however, that this does not restrict the number of edges unless the graph is further assumed to be connected (and even then, it only does if $d=1$ or $d=3.$

Comment: Darn, beat me to it.  If $d = 2$, then the dual $G'$ is isomorphic to $G$, so $d \not= 2$.  However, that still doesn't decide between $d = 1$ or $d = 3$.  I *suspect* the intended answer is $K_4$, but it's unclear.  (It could, for instance, be $K_2$.)

Comment: @BrianTung I did not notice the non-isomorphic thing (reading comprehension issues, I guess). I agree re intended answer, but it is either a sloppy question or a sloppy transmission of a question :)

Comment: sorry, I wrote the question incorrectly. I meant how many edges does L(G) have (assuming at least 1 edge in L(G)

Comment: @GeorgioMahugana That still does not do it, since there are two possibilities (corresponding to degree $1$ and degree $3.$

Comment: Well if G is 1-regular then L(G) is edgeless, so it can't be 1. If G is 3-regular I'm not sure because a 3-regular graph on 4 vertices isn't planar because it is a minor of K3,3 right?

Comment: @GeorgioMahugana: The ambiguity in the question still persists, but assuming the intended $G$ is $K_4$, $G'$ (or, if you prefer, $L(G)$) would have $6$ vertices (one for each edge of $G$) and each of those $6$ vertices would have degree $4$ (one for each edge incident to that edge in $G$), for a total count of $12$ edges.

Comment: @GeorgioMahugana: A graph consisting of a single vertex, I would still consider as a graph.  A degenerate graph, perhaps, but still a graph.  $K_4$ is planar (by Kuratowski), as is its line graph.

Comment: @GeorgioMahugana A graph of degree one does *not* consist of a single vertex. That would be a graph of degree $0.$

Comment: @IgorRivin: I think OP means that the line graph consists of a single vertex.  The line graph (not dual, oops) of $K_2$ is $K_1$.

Comment: @BrianTung I am not seeing the word "dual" anywhere :)

Comment: @IgorRivin: Yeah, sorry, I changed it to "line graph."

Comment: There are cubic planar graphs other than $K_4$ also—for example, the dodecahedron. Even with connectivity, all you know is that your graph is either $K_2$ or a cubic planar graph (all of which are not isomorphic to their line graphs).